# How can React-Router-Dom v6 properly distribute internal routers among components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is routing at the top level with internal routing, the question arose to add routing inside components such as ProductsPage, ElementsPage, etc.

```
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path='/' element={<PageLayout />}>
                            <Route path='marketplace'>
                                <Route path='products' element={<ProductsPage />} />
                                <Route path='constituents' element={<ElementsPage />} />
                                <Route path='resources' element={<ResourcesPage />} />
                                <Route path='shopping' element={<ShoppingPage />} />
                            </Route>
                            <Route path='resource-center'>
                                <Route path='planner' element={<>планирование</>} />
                                <Route path='resources' element={<>resources</>} />
                            </Route>
                            <Route path='*' element={<>Страница не найдена 404</>} />
                        </Route>
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
```

The question is how to do this in version 6. Because before version five, you could easily throw a switch into a component a la ProductsPage and specify routes in the switch

Answer (score 0):

You can name all pages explicitly.

```html
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<PageLayout />} />
        <Route path='/marketplace/products' element={<ProductsPage />} />
        <Route path='/marketplace/constituents' element={<ElementsPage />} />
        <Route path='/marketplace/resources' element={<ResourcesPage />} />
        <Route path='/marketplace/shopping' element={<ShoppingPage />} />
        <Route path='/resource-center/planner' element={<планирование />} />
        <Route path='/resource-centerresources' element={<resources/>} />
        <Route path='*' element={<Страница не найдена 404/>} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```